# Google server is responding with an outdated html file

Tags: c++, httpresponse, winhttp

I'm learning socket programming using C++ , so as a project I thought of a software that downloads all image search results for a certain search(eg."cats"),
I'm using WinHttp and the exemple in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384270(v=vs.85).aspx)
and giving it :

1. **the server name** `L"www.google.com"`
2. **object** `L"/search?q=cats&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP9M3gtZTPAhXLKMAKHYSyDqIQ_AUICCgB&biw=1152&bih=634#q=cats&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:l "`

The problem is that the HTML file in the response message contains what it seems to be an **"Outdated" file That doesn't contain links to the real images**, here it is (I can't give you the whole html file it's too long but here is [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD2ul.png)

**Research:**
I first thought it was a user-agent problem so I added user-agent header, but it didn't work.

**The Problem:** 
I want to get the same HTML result that I get when I search my browser for the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem  it was  the user-agent , just copied the user-agent from my browser